# XML Serialization - Why can't I change the encoding?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

This should hopefully be a simple one.

I am serializaing a List<> of C# objects to an XML document. Everything is going great however my XML document has ASCII encoding (spaces are represented as `X0020` for example) and the client is complaining so I want to change the encoding to UTF8 like so:

```
private void SerializeToXML(List<ResponseData> finalXML)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ResponseData>));
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(txtFileLocation.Text, Encoding.UTF8);
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, finalXML);
    textWriter.Close();
}
```

Intellisense is telling me this should work...

[image: Intellisense]

...but is complaining when I try it...

[image: Error]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The code for space is the same in ASCII and in UTF-8 (like all characters in the 0-127 range)... I don't see any problem here. I think the code is doing what it should, and your client is wrong (yes, I know, the client is always right...)

Comment: `Ecoding.UTF8` is using in `TextWriter` by default. There's no need to pass it in ctor.

Comment: Where are those values appearing? Could you give sample XML?

Comment: Thomas and Dennis, thanks this helps! user845279 appearing in the tags, not the content within.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no (string, Encoding) method signature for the StreamWriter constructor.

There is a (Stream, Encoding) signature for the constructor.

Comment: Aah, wood for the trees and all of that! Thankyou

Comment: A fresh pair of eyes often solves my problems. You are welcome:)

Answer (score 1):

here is a snippet that is working like a charm:

```
using (Stream stream = File.Open(SerializeXmlFileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
         XmlSerializer xmlFormatter = new XmlSerializer(this.Member.GetType());
         xmlFormatter.Serialize(writer, this.Member);
         writer.Close();
    }

    stream.Close();
}
```